# BibTex - polish letter "ł" in translation from chapter

Tags: bibtex, characters, polish

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{plabbrv}` and utf8 coding. I have problem with displaying polish letter "ł" in word "rozdział", which is automatically added when typing the chapter section.

I get something like this:

[image: Result]

main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polski} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plabbrv} 

Cite for the first time \cite{Resnick}.
And this is the second resource \cite{Tchon}.

\bibliography{bibliografia} 
\end{document}
```

bibliografia.bib file:

```
@InBook{Resnick,
author = {David Halliday and Robert Resnick and Jearl Walker},
title = {Podstawy fizyki Tom 1},
chapter = {4},
publisher = {PWN},
year = {2015},
pages = {87--92}
}

@InBook{Tchon,
author = {Krzysztof Tchoń and Alicja Mazur and Ignacy Dulęba and Robert Hossa and Robert Muszyński},
title = {Manipulatory i roboty mobilne},
chapter = {3},
publisher = {PLJ},
year = {2000},
pages = {111-119}
}
```

Comment: The contents of `plabbrv.bst` seem to be faulty, where can we get that file?

Comment: I get it installed automatically with polish packages, here it is:
ftp://ftp.tug.org/tex/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/gustlib/plabbrv.bst

Comment: ok, i found it ;) just needed to change slash into backslash

Comment: @GrzegorzLudwa - Off-topic: Instead of running `\usepackage{polski}`, one could also run `\usepackage[polish]{babel}`.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the `"rozdzia/l"`/`"rozdzia\l"` problem is not limited to the file `plabbrv.bst`: The files `plplain.bst`, `plunsrt.bst`, and `plalpha.bst` all suffer from the exact same problem. I'm afraid I have no idea who the current maintainer(s) of these bst files may be -- or if the four files are even maintained at all. The last time they were updated was in 1994...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can probably use package `polski` (I am writing this post from Technical Univerity Wrocław :-) ), it is enough to write `\prefixing` before your bibliography (and return to `\nonprefixing` after it).

Answer (score 1):

As [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) mentioned there was a problem with the plabbrv.bst file. To solve this you just need to find in this file FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages} and change:

```
{ "rozdzia/l" }
```

into

```
{ "rozdzia\l" }
```

Comment: Please note that it is bad practice to change files from the distribution without renaming them. I suggest you copy the file, rename it to `plabbrv-fixedl.bst` and change that file. Indeed it would be against the license of `plabbrv.bst` to distribute a modified version under the same name.